# Get the row indexes for retained columns in pandas merge

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently using `pandas.merge` to find aligned rows between two different pandas frames as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=5, freq='T')
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'timestamp': rng, 'Val': np.random.randn(len(rng)) })
df_1 = df_1.drop(df_1.index[[0]])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'timestamp': rng, 'Val': np.random.randn(len(rng)) })
df_2 = df_2.drop(df_2.index[[4]])

common_rows = pd.merge(df_1, 
                       df_2.reset_index(), 
                       how='inner', 
                       on=['timestamp'])
```

This works as expected and gives me a unified pandas frame back but what I would like to know is which row indexes are retained in both the dataframes. My need is to be able to filter out the two dataframes and only keep these common rows rather than have this unified view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow through with your approach, using `suffixes` argument:

```py
common_rows = pd.merge(df_1.reset_index(), 
                       df_2.reset_index(), 
                       how='inner', 
                       on=['timestamp'],
                       suffixes=['_1', '_2']
                       )

df_1 = df_1.loc[common_rows.index_1.unique()]
df_2 = df_2.loc[common_rows.index_2.unique()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reindex` to keep common rows:

```
df_1 = df_1.set_index('timestamp') \
           .reindex(df_2['timestamp']) \
           .dropna(how='all') \
           .reset_index()

df_2 = df_2.set_index('timestamp') \
           .reindex(df_1['timestamp']) \
           .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> df_1
            timestamp       Val
0 2015-02-24 00:01:00 -0.833354
1 2015-02-24 00:02:00 -1.445002
2 2015-02-24 00:03:00 -2.106964

>>> df_2
            timestamp       Val
0 2015-02-24 00:01:00  0.863396
1 2015-02-24 00:02:00  0.263386
2 2015-02-24 00:03:00 -0.169489
```